# Summing values in list of pairs in scala by common element

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I have a list of `String`, `Double` pairs:

```
List((Db,0.1574), (C,1.003), (Db,15.4756), (D,0.003), (Bb,1.4278), (D,13.0001))
```

I want to `sum` the double values that have common string value and create a new list of pairs thus:

```
List((Db, 15.633), (C, 1.003), (D, 13.0031), (Bb, 1.4278)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: what is the option you tried in REPL

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupBy` is a good place to start:

```
list
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
  .toList
```

You can also use `foldLeft` to sum the values but it is probably less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
scala> val a = List(("Db",0.1574), ("C",1.003), ("Db",15.4756), ("D",0.003), ("Bb",1.4278), ("D",13.0001))
a: List[(String, Double)] = List((Db,0.1574), (C,1.003), (Db,15.4756), (D,0.003), (Bb,1.4278), (D,13.0001))

scala> a.groupBy( x=> x._1).map(x=> (x._1,x._2.map(a=>a._2).sum))
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double] = Map(D -> 13.0031, Db -> 15.633000000000001, C -> 1.003, Bb -> 1.4278)

scala>
scala> a.groupBy( x=> x._1).map(x=> (x._1,x._2.map(a=>a._2).sum)).toList
res12: List[(String, Double)] = List((D,13.0031), (Db,15.633000000000001), (C,1.003), (Bb,1.4278))

scala>
```